# SVG manipulation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jsx

I am trying to create a simple graphics in SVG showing an equipment on a line. This equipment should have a label underneath. I want the labels to not overlap:
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36xMQ.png)
. Since I am using React I want to write the SVG code in JSX syntax in the `render()` function. So for simplicity lets assume I only have:

**Equipment class**

```
const Equipment = (props) => (
    <g>
        <rect
          x={props.x}
          y={props.y}
          width={props.width}
          height={props.height}
          fill={black}
        />
        <text
          x={props.x}
          y={props.y}
          fill={black}
          fontSize={props.size}
        >
            {props.text}
        </text>
    </g>
);

export default Equipment;
```

**SVG main class**

```
import Equipment from './Equipment';

const SVG = (props) => (
    <svg
      width='100%'
      height='100%'
    >
        <g transform={`matrix(${props.matrix})`}>
            <Equipment
              x={10}
              y={10}
              width={100}
              height={100}
              fontSize={props.size}
              test='Equipment 1'
            />
            <Equipment
              x={60}
              y={10}
              width={50}
              height={100}
              fontSize={props.size}
              test='Equipment 2'
            />
        </g>
    </svg>
);

export default SVG;
```

I use transformation matrices to scale everything in the SVG but maintaining the size of the text to some constant inverse to scale in the matrix.

1. How do I ensure the labels are not overlapping?
2. Is there a declarative way or do I have to use while loop?

NOTE: Surely this is something that can be easily done when creating the SVG object manually and using SVG functions like `checkIntersection` or `getIntersectionList` but those are not available on the React components and I would like to keep the JSX syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to add a prop such as textPositionY that indicates the vertical position of the text. Also a function that generates this position from depending on the index of the SVG element. Somithing like this:

```
 {
   svgArray.map((eachSVG, index) => {
      const pxFromTop = 20;
      const generateTextPositionY = ix => fixedPosition + ix * pxFromTop;
      const currentTextPositionY = generateTextPositionY(index);
      const svgKey = `svgKey-${index}`

      return (
        <YourSVGComponent
          key={svgKey}
          textPositionY={currentTextPositionY}
          ...your other props
        />
   )})
 }
```

Next, with this prop you can set the styles for your texts, because you know how many px from the top each text is.